# When I visit my website there is only slash(-) showing intead of home or my website name. how to solve this? I am attaching image also to understand

Tags: wp-query

When I visit my website there is only slash(-) showing instead of home or my website name. how to solve this? I am attaching image also to understand.

Comment: Hello, there is no picture attached as indicated in the question. Are you meaning your website title? You can change that by going into Settings > General, and changing the "Site Title" box.

Comment: @YourManDan I suspect that's the problem, so I suggest posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Settings > General page in your WordPress backend. Then check to make sure the "Site Title" is what you'd expect it to be.